# webview splash screen when no internet access

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple `WebView` app built from http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

If there is no internet access, I want to add some image or message. How to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code to check internet connection:

```
public static boolean hasConnection() {
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) MbridgeApp.getContext().getSystemService(
    Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
  return true;
}

NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
  return true;
}

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
  return true;
}

return false;
```

}

Also add the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permissions to your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Just open a local HTML file with a page that contains a JS script that checks if it can reach the internet and if so, browses to the page. Otherwise, your image would be shown.
Something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  body.onload = function() {
    if(navigator.onLine) {
      location = "http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html";
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="x.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But, webview app is on Java. Where I have to create that html file?

Comment: Include it with your package. Save to local resources. Open from WebView

Comment: Am i right:
I have to add your html page to the package and, for example, call it start.html

then, in java file change
`mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");`
to
`mWebView.loadUrl("/start.html");`

webview will open this local script, which redirect user to the site. If there is no internet, in will show image. Correct?